# Multiple instance of the same provider

Tags: guice

I created an DataSourceProvider to look up container managed dataSource:

```
public class ContainerDataSourceProvider implements Provider<DataSource> {
    private final DataSource ds;

    @Inject
    ContainerDataSourceProvider (String dataSourceName) throws NamingException {
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/" + dataSourceName);
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource get() {
        return ds;
    }
}
```

I can't used @Named annotation on the provider since I want to be able to provide different datasource depending on dataSourceName.

In my module, I want to provide multiple dataSource bindings using the provider.  The name of the jdni datasorce comes from a property file already binded to Names.

```
//How do I configure ContainerDataSourceProvider with jndi name "userDataSource"????
binder.bind(DataSource.class).annotatedWith(UserDS.class)
                .toProvider(ContainerDataSourceProvider.class);

//How do I configure ContainerDataSourceProvider with jndi name "sessionDataSource"????
binder.bind(DataSource.class).annotatedWith(SessionDS.class)
                .toProvider(ContainerDataSourceProvider.class);
```

Then in my code, I will be able to do something like

```
public class UserDSClient {
       @Inject UserDSClient (@UserDS DataSource ds) {}
}

public class SessionDSClient {
       @Inject SessionDSClient (@SessionDS DataSource ds) {}
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple. Create the provider manually, passing datasource name to its constructor:

```
public class ContainerDataSourceProvider implements Provider<DataSource> {
    private final String dataSourceName;

    @Inject
    ContainerDataSourceProvider (String dataSourceName) {
        this.dataSourceName = dataSourceName;
    }

    @Override
    public DataSource get() {
        try {
            Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
            Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
            return (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/" + dataSourceName);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also moved context lookup code to `get()` method. This is completely safe in terms of performance if you put the bindings in singleton scope - Guice is smart enough to call provider method only once in this case. Here are the bindings:

```
binder.bind(DataSource.class).annotatedWith(UserDS.class)
    .toProvider(new ContainerDataSourceProvider("userDataSource"))
    .in(Singleton.class);

binder.bind(DataSource.class).annotatedWith(SessionDS.class)
    .toProvider(new ContainerDataSourceProvider("sessionDataSource"))
    .in(Singleton.class);
```

That is all.

BTW, because for some reason lookup may fail, you will get an exception during dependency resolution time (either in `Guice.createInjector()` call or in `injector.getInstance()` call), both in your code, when exception is thrown from the constructor, and in my variant. Consider using [throwing providers](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ThrowingProviders) extension if you need to handle this error.

Answer (score 0):

I **strongly** recommend you to use [Private Modules](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html). Private module will hide all binding information from environment. So, you will be able to inject different implementation to the same interface without the use of an `Annotations`.

Well, I made a presentation. Maybe it will help you get the idea around Private modules. http://slid.es/milanbaran/dec