# Bind different JacksonJsonProvider to different jersey resources using Guice

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, guice

I have a web app with versionned API. In the next version of the API, I want to serialize my joda DateTime object using the ISO format (2013-12-14T00:00:00.000Z) instead of the EPOCH format.

I achieved my goal by using a custom serializer that I coded and adding it to the objectMapper of my jacksonJsonProvider. The problem, the serialization of DateTime object changed for all versions of my API (which is bad, since I don't want any breaking change in the API).

Is there a way to specify to the jersey resource which jacksonJsonProvider to use? (as I said in the title, I am using Guice as  my DI framework).

EDIT

I am using version 1.7.1 of Jersey and 4.0-beta of guice

Comment: what version of jersey are you using?

Comment: I edited the question to add the information you wanted.

Comment: How do you expose your versionned APIs? I assume each version has its own Module, probably server module. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved via `annotated bindings` or better `private modules`. I need more information from you to help you further, check my comment under your question.

Look at my post how to encapsulate modules. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20073461/2616445

Comment: I looked at the presentation you linked in the other post (ti's very nice btw) and the private modules look very promising.

Comment: Thanks! Good to hear you like the presentation. If you find something hard to understand or you stuck somewhere. Let me know...